# Can I bake / flatten an UIImageView including its layer with rounded corners and masksToBounds

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit, uiimage

I'm trying to flatten some images I get from a server down to 40 x 40 thumbnails, so I can save them in /Library/Caches and use those instead with UITableViewCell's UIImage.

So far, I know how bake / flatten an image like so:

```
 UIImage *newThumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]]];

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(40, 40));
  [newThumbnail drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 40, 40)];
  newThumbnail = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();      
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  [UIImagePNGRepresentation(newThumbnail) writeToFile:imageCachePath atomically:YES];
```

I'd also like to include rounded corners in the flattened image. But right now, I create the rounded corners by manipulating the layer of the UIImageView that hosts the UIIMage. Like so:

```
  imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 7.0;
  imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
  imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
  imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
```

So how do I include the above layer modifications into the whole UIGraphicsBeginImageContext mechanism? Or is there any better way of doing  it?

Comment: Have you tried to include the above lines into the UIView's init function? That should have done the trick.

Comment: I've tried creating the UIImage and including it in an UIImageView, then setting the UIImageView layer properties like above and then doing the context push / pop but the layer properties (rounded corner, mask to bound) don't show up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option (1), which involves more learning and more work, but is more flexible:

Take a look through the CGContextRef docs.

Figure how to draw a rounded corner path. (There's a bunch of sample code floating around the internets using the CTM.)

To simulate `cornerRadius` and `masksToBounds`, use that path to set a clipping path before drawing your image.

To simulate the `borderColor` plus `borderWidth`, set an appropriate stroke color and width and then stroke that path.

Option (2):

Try rendering your `UIImageView.layer` into your context with `renderInContext:`.

Comment: Thanks for the info! In the meantime, I kept trying on my own and found out about renderInContext. I was just missing that call. Thanks.